# Flash CS5 Symbol Button Fill is hidding the stroke

Tags: flash-cs5

A bunch of paths are imported from Illustrator to Flash and converted to Button Symbols. The Stroke is set to Hairline (0.10) Light Gray and the Fill to solid White for all of the paths. When the file loads the Fill colors are provided from an XML file and can be Red/Blue etc. My problem is that the Solid Fill covers/hides the Stroke/borders.

As workaround I copied all paths to another layer placed on top of the symbols layer. So all symbols are behind and the top layer simulates the borders.

Is any way to make the Symbols border to be displayed without having that extra layer? I tried using very Heavy/Thick border setting but still the fill is hiding it.